# Very Strange Drive Mounting Error in Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, mount, hard-drive

this question is not really a programming question, but I figured I'd post it here because it does seem to be a software error, and you guys are experts.
I use a Lacie 1TB external HDD and have been perfectly happy with it so far. I plugged it into my laptop today and all my files were gone and replaced by the files from a CD-ROM I was using a couple of days ago. (Kaspersky Rescue)
I panicked a bit because all of my stuff is on that drive, but I plugged it into another computer to check if all my files really were gone, and they were still there.
So...
In my laptop:
 - Drive label is LaCie
 - Files displayed are Kaspersky rescue disk files

- I can open these files and edit their contents (so they must be cached somewhere)
  On the other computer:
- Drive label is LaCie
- All my files are intact

Any suggestions???
Thankyou!

Comment: If you know it is off topic, why ask?

Comment: From [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq): "Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast **programmers**". Programming and tech support are not equivalent tasks.

Comment: Can you turn disable all of the Kaspersky services and startup programs, reboot and then see if the drive appears normal?

Comment: The labeling issue has me confused (kind of like the floppy change indicator issue in days of old). Otherwise see if anything here may help?  "No Drive Letter in the Windows Explorer"
http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbtrouble_e.html

"USBDLM V4.2.3 - USB Drive Letter Manager for Windows 2000, XP, Server 2003 and Vista"
http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm_e.html

"Tips for USB pen drives"
http://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbstick_e.html

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it might be a drive letter conflict.

Connect your external disk, wait a few seconds, then open the disk management console from the run menu:

Start > Run... > diskmgmt.msc

Hopefully your disk will appear in the list at the bottom, somwhere below "Disk 0". Right-click on the large (~1TB) partition on the disk, then choose "Change drive letters and paths". Change the drive letter to something you know is not in use. Close the disk management console and check Windows explorer.